# How to set value of static fields in ignite run configurations in xml

Tags: xml, spring, ignite

here is the bean part.

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
     <property name="name" value="cfgCache"/>
     <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
     <property name="static.DFLT_CACHE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>
     <!--property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/-->
</bean>
```

how to set the value of DFLT_CACHE_SIZE? 
or any static field?

Docs:

```
static int  DFLT_CACHE_SIZE
Default cache size to use with eviction policy.
DFLT_CACHE_SIZE = 256MB
```

Apache ignite is based on spring framework.

Err

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'grid.cfg' defined in URL [file:/home/ignite/sample-cache.xml]: Cannot create inner bean
 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration#4cc0edeb' of type [org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration] while setting bean
 property 'cacheConfiguration' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
 name 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration#4cc0edeb' defined in URL [file:/home/ignite/sample-cache.xml]: Error setting property
 values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'DFLT_CACHE_SIZE' of bean class
 [org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration]: Bean property 'DFLT_CACHE_SIZE' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the
 parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting this default value you can override it by setting max field in eviction policies for Ignite. For example:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="cfgCache"/>
            <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
            <property name="evictionPolicy">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.sorted.SortedEvictionPolicy">
                    <property name="maxSize" value="100"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static final int DFLT_CACHE_SIZE = 100000;`

It isn't just static field. It's a **final** field, there's no way to change it with a spring config.